# Freeswitch : Audio handshake failure 1 error while making call using Sipml5

Tags: voip, sip, freeswitch

I just installed **FreeSwitch** and **successfully connected** to server with user 1001.

**Details ->**
**OS** - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bits
**FS** - 1.5.13b+git~20140614T114905Z~fc7a74905b~64bit
**OpenSSL** - 1.0.1
**chrome** - 31, 35

**webrtc** is enabled.
websocket - ws://192.168.32.181:9066
Outbound Proxy - udp://192.168.32.181:5060

**Case 1 -**
Call from browser ( Sipml5 ) to Twinkle  [ 1001 -> 1005]
ring bell but terminated immediately.
it throws the error -> **[ERR] switch_rtp.c:2746 audio Handshake failure 1**

Here is the console output of FS.

```
2014-06-15 17:46:53.169179 [CONSOLE] mod_voicemail.c:4066 Event Thread Started
2014-06-15 17:46:57.709189 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1053 New Channel sofia/internal/1001@192.168.32.181 [fdfafcf3-9740-479d-88b9-86fc9bd5ba48]
2014-06-15 17:46:57.789172 [INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:558 Processing 1001 <1001>->5000 in context default
2014-06-15 17:46:57.869188 [WARNING] switch_core_media.c:2634 NO candidate ACL defined, Defaulting to wan.auto
2014-06-15 17:46:57.869188 [NOTICE] switch_core_media.c:2672 Save audio Candidate cid: 1 proto: udp type: host addr: 192.168.32.181:45250
2014-06-15 17:46:57.869188 [NOTICE] switch_core_media.c:2672 Save audio Candidate cid: 2 proto: udp type: host addr: 192.168.32.181:45250
2014-06-15 17:46:57.869188 [NOTICE] switch_core_media.c:2667 Choose audio Candidate cid: 1 proto: udp type: srflx addr: 103.25.231.2:45250
2014-06-15 17:46:57.869188 [NOTICE] switch_core_media.c:2667 Choose audio Candidate cid: 2 proto: udp type: srflx addr: 103.25.231.2:45250
2014-06-15 17:46:57.929181 [NOTICE] switch_core_media.c:2796 setting remote audio ice addr to 103.25.231.2:45250 based on candidate
2014-06-15 17:46:57.929181 [NOTICE] switch_core_media.c:2816 setting remote rtcp audio addr to 103.25.231.2:45250 based on candidate
2014-06-15 17:46:57.949179 [INFO] switch_core_media.c:5099 Activating Audio ICE
2014-06-15 17:46:57.949179 [NOTICE] switch_rtp.c:3827 Activating RTP audio ICE: arHk82ejwwYXx/pE:OgS3O4Uf7pKvkZ7Z 103.25.231.2:45250
2014-06-15 17:46:57.949179 [INFO] switch_core_media.c:5142 Activating RTCP PORT 45250
2014-06-15 17:46:57.949179 [INFO] switch_core_media.c:5150 Skipping RTCP ICE (Same as RTP)
2014-06-15 17:46:57.949179 [INFO] switch_rtp.c:2930 Activate RTP/RTCP audio DTLS client
2014-06-15 17:46:57.969177 [NOTICE] sofia_media.c:92 Pre-Answer sofia/internal/1001@192.168.32.181!
2014-06-15 17:46:57.969177 [NOTICE] mod_dptools.c:1258 Channel [sofia/internal/1001@192.168.32.181] has been answered
2014-06-15 17:46:58.089172 [NOTICE] switch_rtp.c:1144 Auto Changing stun/rtp/dtls port from 103.25.231.2:45250 to 192.168.32.181:45250
**2014-06-15 17:46:59.149182 [ERR] switch_rtp.c:2746 audio Handshake failure 1**
2014-06-15 17:46:59.149182 [INFO] switch_rtp.c:2747 Changing audio DTLS state from HANDSHAKE to FAIL
2014-06-15 17:46:59.149182 [NOTICE] switch_rtp.c:2728 Hangup sofia/internal/1001@192.168.32.181 [CS_EXECUTE] [DESTINATION_OUT_OF_ORDER]
2014-06-15 17:46:59.209173 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1632 Session 1 (sofia/internal/1001@192.168.32.181) Ended
2014-06-15 17:46:59.209173 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1636 Close Channel sofia/internal/1001@192.168.32.181 [CS_DESTROY]
2014-06-15 17:51:42.289180 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1053 New Channel sofia/internal/1005@192.168.32.181 [82cde687-c8a7-4613-8221-f282c03190ef]
```

**Case 2 -**
Call from Twinkle to web browser (sipml5) [1005 -> 1001 ]
call is made
received at browser end.
Call terminates.

**Error -  Core dumped (Segmentation fault)**

FS output -

```
2014-06-15 20:11:58.529178 [INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:558 Processing 1005 <1005>->1001 in context default
2014-06-15 20:11:58.529178 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3640 Bound B-Leg: *1 execute_extension::dx XML features
2014-06-15 20:11:58.529178 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3640 Bound B-Leg: *2 record_session::/usr/local/freeswitch/recordings/1005.2014-06-15-20-11-58.wav
2014-06-15 20:11:58.529178 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3640 Bound B-Leg: *3 execute_extension::cf XML features
2014-06-15 20:11:58.529178 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3640 Bound B-Leg: *4 execute_extension::att_xfer XML features
2014-06-15 20:11:58.529178 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1053 New Channel sofia/internal/sip:1001@df7jal23ls0d.invalid [84d5b24f-07f5-43b8-ac2f-7fc091e712c2]
2014-06-15 20:11:58.589178 [NOTICE] sofia.c:6325 Ring-Ready sofia/internal/sip:1001@df7jal23ls0d.invalid!
2014-06-15 20:11:58.589178 [INFO] switch_ivr_originate.c:1192 Sending early media
2014-06-15 20:11:58.589178 [NOTICE] sofia_media.c:92 Pre-Answer sofia/internal/1005@192.168.32.181!
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [WARNING] switch_core_media.c:2634 NO candidate ACL defined, Defaulting to wan.auto
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [NOTICE] switch_core_media.c:2672 Save audio Candidate cid: 1 proto: udp type: host addr: 192.168.32.181:41485
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [NOTICE] switch_core_media.c:2667 Choose audio Candidate cid: 1 proto: udp type: srflx addr: 103.25.231.2:41485
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [NOTICE] switch_core_media.c:2761 No audio RTCP candidate found; defaulting to the same as RTP [103.25.231.2:41485]
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [NOTICE] switch_core_media.c:2796 setting remote audio ice addr to 103.25.231.2:41485 based on candidate
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [NOTICE] switch_core_media.c:2816 setting remote rtcp audio addr to 103.25.231.2:41485 based on candidate
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [INFO] switch_core_media.c:5099 Activating Audio ICE
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [NOTICE] switch_rtp.c:3827 Activating RTP audio ICE: oNkIBm25ryyPPARl:JWMrFJEDlPAW6Ehl 103.25.231.2:41485
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [INFO] switch_core_media.c:5142 Activating RTCP PORT 41485
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [INFO] switch_core_media.c:5150 Skipping RTCP ICE (Same as RTP)
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [INFO] switch_rtp.c:2930 Activate RTP/RTCP audio DTLS server
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [NOTICE] sofia.c:7063 Channel [sofia/internal/sip:1001@df7jal23ls0d.invalid] has been answered
2014-06-15 20:12:01.909176 [NOTICE] switch_ivr_originate.c:3494 Channel [sofia/internal/1005@192.168.32.181] has been answered
2014-06-15 20:12:01.949181 [NOTICE] switch_rtp.c:1144 Auto Changing stun/rtp/dtls port from 103.25.231.2:41485 to 192.168.32.181:41485
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Please Help.

Comment: Looks like a NAT failure. Describe the networks the client and server are on.

Comment: working on local network i.e LAN. FS is installed on one system and I am trying to make a call using web based softphone (Sipml5) from same system.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a segfault you should fill a JIRA at http://jira.freeswitch.org, With logs and all data needed to resolve the issue related to your crash.

Start here:

https://confluence.freeswitch.org/display/FREESWITCH/Reporting+Bugs